Celery leaves messages that failed all retries in unacked state
I have a couple rabbitmq/celery tasks that, for reasons I cannot control, like API restrictions, will inevitably fail. I wrap them in what seems "reasonable" for my retries, for example:
@retriable_task(MyException, retry_countdown=60, random_factor=0.2, max_retries=10, exponential_factor=4)

and it usually works after a few retires. However, and I think I'm missing something conceptually here, it seems that this retires leave the message in a sort of "unacked" state where even if the worker is available, it's not actually consumed until something (I'm not sure what) causes it to be acknowledged. See for example the 406 messages here:

I would expect the message be asked and put back into the queue somehow, but I may be missing something. I believe late ack might be the way forward but I don't really see why?
